# populate a container with objects sorted by nonmember values [c++]

Tags: c++, sorting, containers

I am doing some sampling of points in multidimensional vector spaces.
The points are simply implemented as `vector<double>` with each entry being the value of that points corresponding coordinate.

What I want to end up with is a list of these samples orderes by some function value.

Since computing the function may be costly, I want to do it only once and not every time a new sample is added to the container.
A `std::multiset` is almost what I want, but appears to only be capable of sorting based on inherent or overloaded `operator<`.

Of course I could simply do something like

```
struct point {
    point(vector<double> pos, double val) : pos(pos), val(val) {}
    vector<double> pos;
    double val;
    bool operator< (const point & rhs) const{
        return val < rhs.val;
    };
};
```

and be done with it, but it seems like there should be some efficient standard sorted container type that keeps track of the key without it needing to be a member's attribute (and thus requiring such a wrapper workaround).

Comment: `std::multimap`?

Comment: Oh my I think it's getting a bit late. That seems almost too obvious! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A multimap from calculated double to vector.  If you need to reverse it, a map from vector to double as well.

You could shave the double off by storing a pointer to the caching vector to double in a multiset of vector's comparison, but that seems unwise.